# How to insert data into text area from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I am trying to retrieve data from mysql and put into text area. Others data that insert to text box works well but i faced problem when want to insert into text area.

```
echo'<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="200" value="'.$abstract.'"></textarea>';
```

I have fetch my query out with

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publication where file_id='$id'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $abstract=$row1['abstract'];
```

Thanks for helping me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
echo'<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="200">'.$abstract.'</textarea>';

or 
<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="200"><?php echo $abstract?></textarea>
```

Comment: The first statement `echo'<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="200">$abstract</textarea>';` , will not work as expected ... PHP string interpolation doesn't work with `'` single quote ... `echo 'hello $name';` will print **hello $name**

Comment: echo'<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="200">'.$abstract.'</textarea>'; will work

Answer (score 3):

Textarea doesn't have *value* tag:

```
echo'<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="200">'.$abstract.'</textarea>';
```

Answer (score 1):

use as

```
echo '<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="200">'.$abstract.'</textarea>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `$abstract` like this :

```
echo'<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="200">'.$abstract.'</textarea>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<textarea name="abstract" id="abstract" size="200" ><?php echo $abstract; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid concatenation  you could enclose the variable within curly braces to avoid any confusion, if it does, in the following manner

```
echo "<textarea name='abstract' id='abstract' size='200'>{$abstract}</textarea>";
```